# Why are global using aliases not available in my unit test project?

Tags: c#

I have a `Foo.csproj` with a class in it: `Utils.cs`. In my `Foo.Tests.csproj`, I have a `UtilsTest.cs`. In `Utils.cs`, I have a global alias:

```cs
global using ProfileDataCollection =
    System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, TrashLib.Sonarr.ReleaseProfile.ProfileData>;
```

I was expecting `ProfileDataCollection` to now be usable everywhere, sort of like C++ typedefs. However, I'm not able to resolve this symbol from `UtilsTest.cs`. Do global usings not cross project-dependency boundaries?

I'm using .NET 6 + C# 10 with `<ImplicitUsings>` set to `enable`.

Comment: *"everywhere"* is still limited to the project where you define the alias. The unit test project doesn't inherit that by way of reference. You have to declare the alias there, too. C++ `typedef`s still have to be defined in each source file, usually by including a header file.

Comment: It could be all source files in a project https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#global-using-directives